# How to get the isLoading state while keepPreviousData is on in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I would like to keep the previous data and using a spinner on top of the data while loading.

I know that isLoading only return true if it is hard loading. However, using isFetching will trigger spinner to appear whenever there is background fetch.

Is there any way to get the loading state when keepPreviousData is on?

Comment: This is desired behaviour of react query to prevent jumping in and out of the success and loading states.

Comment: How to achieve the feature under this circumstances?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A good way to do this is to use the `isPreviousData` flag that is also returned from `useQuery`. It will be `true` for as long as the previous data is shown due to `keepPreviousData`, and as soon as the "real data" for that query comes back, it will go back to `false`.

This is for example how we disable the next-button in the [pagination example](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/60eb97425f7f39dc94805cf4a929777ccfb29e8a/examples/pagination/pages/index.js#L79)

Comment: feel free to accept and upvote the answer then :)